# Is it accurate to say that the rotation group is diffeomorphic to $RP^3$?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

I come from a physics background, so I know I might be overseeing some math subtitles. I know that SO(3) is diffeomorphic to $RP^3$, but my question if this statement can be extended to the rotation group in general. For example SU(2) is another representation of the rotation group but it's not diffeomorphic to $RP^3$. However, the rotation group still seems to be closely related to $RP^3$.

What is the precise mathematical relationship between the rotation group and $RP^3$?

Comment: $\text{SO}(3)$ is the quotient lie group $\text{SU}(2)/\{I,-I \}$. This is because every rotation arises from *two* unit quaternions.

Comment: Does this make SU(2) also diffeomorphic to $RP^3$?

Comment: No, $\text{SU}(2)$ is what is called a 2-sheeted covering space for $\text{SO}(3)$. $\text{SU}(2)$ is isomorphic as a lie group to the unit quaternions, i.e $S^3$.

Comment: Oh  yeah I get that. Sorry this is still not obvious to me. So you mean that indeed the rotation group is diffeomorphic to $RP^3$?

Comment: If by "rotation group" you mean $SO(3)$ then yes.

Comment: Well yes. But can't I think of the rotation group independent of its representations?

Comment: Yes but you have to define what a rotation is mathematically first. Often a rotation is simply defined as an element of $SO(3)$

Comment: $SO(2)$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$, and in particular not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: @NoelLundström can’t we just take the group Lie algebra as the definition?